# How to specify EC2 computation resource for AWS datapipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to create different kind of pipelines but I am not able to specify an EC2 computation resource properly .I have my EC2 instances and I'm providing their subnet ID,it still however doesn't work.
Do I have to create a different kind of computation resource all together
Please let me know steps to configure this in console

Comment: what doesn't work? give more detail.

Comment: It asks for a default subnet ID from anEC2 vpc.. I can see in the dependencies and the  EC2 resource is in red

Answer (score 0):

Do try looking up into the [AWS Data Pipeline Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/what-is-datapipeline.html).

And, some tutorials [tutorials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/welcome.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

"I have my EC2 instances and I'm providing their subnet ID"

To clarify, you need not create resource beforehand. Datapipeline creates EC2 resource on your behalf. All you have to do is specify what kind of resource to launch in your pipeline definition.

datapipeline documentation on EC2 resource object: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-ec2resource.html

you can also check out various datapipeline samples in github: https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples